# Django - Context dictionary for attribute inside a class

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I want to display a list of an attribute of one specific class in my Django app.
For example displaying all the titles of a Blog Post:

Models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

And then in my context dictionary I'm getting the error:

Type object 'BlogPost' has no attribute 'title'

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    blog_list = BlogPost.title # I understand here is the issue. 
    context_dict = {'blog': blog_list}
    return render_to_response('rango/blog.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: What is `blog_list`?

Comment: @user3100115 It is supposed to be a list of all the titles, how can I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`title` is an instance attribute in your model that is why you are getting this error message that being said to get a list of all `title` value you can use the [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) method

```
blog_list = [post['title'] for post in BlogPost.objects.values('title')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `BlogPost.title` gets you that attribute of the *class*, when you need that attribute of the *instances*, which you get by doing `BlogPost.objects.all()`. So this code will work, though it is slower than the method shown in [user3100115's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33884044/1473772).

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    blog_list = []
    for blog_post in BlogPost.objects.all():
        blog_list.append(blog_post.title)
    context_dict = {'blog': blog_list}
    return render_to_response('rango/blog.html', context_dict, context)
```

Or, by using list comprehension:

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    blog_list = [bp.title for bp in BlogPost.objects.all()]
    context_dict = {'blog': blog_list}
    return render_to_response('rango/blog.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, using `.values("title")` will be faster, since it will have to load less information from the database.

Comment: @ddsnowboard definitely yes.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman don't edit because I  already posted that answer

Comment: @user3100115: I saw that; I've added a link instead and +1'd.

Answer (score 2):

You want this

```
blog_list = [b.title for b in BlogPost.objects.values("title")]
```

This is a list comprehension. It will make a `ValuesQuerySet` (not much more than a `list` of `dict`s) of the `title`s all of your `BlogPost`s objects, then put all the titles in a list.

You were looking at the `BlogPost` `Model`, not the objects themselves. You have to get one or more objects with a query (in this case, an implied `.all()`) in order to see their properties.